# How to pass quoted arguments from variable to bash script

Tags: bash, escaping, command-line-arguments, quotes

I tried building a set of arguments in a variable and passing that to a script but the behavior different from what I expected.

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

for var in "$@"; do
  echo "$var"
done
```

**input**

```
usr@host$ ARGS="-a \"arg one\" -b \"arg two\""
usr@host$ ./test.sh $ARGS
```

**output**

```
-a
"arg
one"
-b
"arg
two"
```

**expected**

```
-a
arg one
-b
arg two
```

Note if you pass the quoted arguments directly to the script it works.  I also can work around this with eval but I wanted to understand why the first approach failed.

**workaround**

```
ARGS="./test.sh -a "arg one" -b "arg two""
eval $ARGS
```

Comment: FYI, `for var in "$@; do"` is the same as `for var; do`.

Comment: eval is not a workaround, it is the way to do this.

Comment: @EranBen-Natan, using `eval` [compromises security](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). It's utterly unsuited for situations where data is not hand-written by someone at least as trusted as the software's developer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use an array, which in some sense provides a 2nd level of quoting:

```
ARGS=(-a "arg one" -b "arg two")
./test.sh "${ARGS[@]}"
```

The array expansion produces one word per element of the array, so that the whitespace you quoted when the array was created is not treated as a word separator when constructing the list of arguments that are passed to `test.sh`.

Note that arrays are not supported by the POSIX shell, but this is the precise shortcoming in the POSIX shell that arrays were introduced to correct.