# How to handle multiple arguments with spaces in a passed sh var?

Tags: printf, sh, posix

I have a posix sh script that runs another command. The second command can have zero, one or multiple options passed. These options are passed as an env var, e.g. `$OPTIONS`. However, some of the options can have spaces in them.

E.g. If my executed command is `curl`, then my option is `CURL_OPTIONS`.

```
#!/bin/sh
# do some processing
curl $CURL_OPTIONS https://some.example.com
```

As long as none of the `CURL_OPTIONS` contains whitespace, I am fine, e.g.

```
CURL_OPTIONS="--user me:pass --user-agent foo"
```

However, if the options contain space, the sh expands it out and treats each like its own var:

```
CURL_OPTIONS="--header 'Authorization: token abcdefg'"
```

I *can* run `curl --header 'Authorization: token abcdefg' https://some.url.com`, since the sh will interpret the single quotes `'` and pass `Authorization: token abcdefg` as a single parameter to `curl`, and all is fine.

However, because I am working with a var, the sh expands it out upon seeing `$CURL_OPTIONS` and does not interpret the single-quoted `Authorization: token abcdefg` as a single parameter. The result of the above is:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: token
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: abcdefg'
```

(Note that it even treats the single quote as part of `abcdefg'`.)

Yes, I have seen [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162010/posix-sh-equivalent-for-bash-s-printf-q) , none of which seems to work in this case.

UPDATE:

Oh, now this is interesting https://stackoverflow.com/a/31485948/736714 
Why didn't I think of `xargs`?

Comment: using `eval` is an option? https://serverfault.com/a/875449/94862

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: Reading quoted/escaped arguments correctly from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067249/bash-reading-quoted-escaped-arguments-correctly-from-a-string)

Comment: Yeah, I found the `xargs` recommendation afterwards, but decided to leave it up.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this works.

```
CURL_OPTIONS=(--header "Authorization: token abcdefg")
curl "${CURL_OPTIONS[@]}" www.example.com
```

[How to pass quoted arguments from variable to bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012991/how-to-pass-quoted-arguments-from-variable-to-bash-script)

UPDATE:
I'm guessing this next snippet should be POSIX-compliant (it's a bit of an escape-hell, though)

```
CURL_OPTIONS="--header \\\"Authorization:\ token\ abcdefg\\\""
eval set -- $CURL_OPTIONS
curl "$@" www.example.com
```

Comment: Arrays aren't available in POSIX sh.

Comment: Yeah, that is escape hell, and @JohnKugelman is right that I need POSIX, not `bash`. The problem with this answer is that it requires, as you said, "escape-hell", which I cannot impose on the users of the command.